# Updating multiple rows in mysql database with serialized form data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update multiple rows in my database with data coming from an html form data via AJAX. I don't have any problem with updating the database but I used several queries to update each row. What is the PROPER way to update multiple rows coming from a big form using AJAX? A foreach loop?

```
if ( isset($_POST['updateData']) ) {
    parse_str($_POST['fields']);

    $update1 = $db->execute("UPDATE content SET content_text=? WHERE page_id = '".$page_id."' AND lang_code = '".$lang_code."' AND content_id =1", array($field1));
    $update2 = $db->execute("UPDATE content SET title=?, content_text=? WHERE page_id = '".$page_id."' AND lang_code = '".$lang_code."' AND content_id =2", array($field2_title, $field2));
    $update3 = $db->execute("UPDATE content SET title=? WHERE page_id = '".$page_id."' AND lang_code = '".$lang_code."' AND content_id =3", array($field3_title));

}
```

My database

```
ID | content_id | page_id | lang_code | title      | content_text |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1          | 2       | en        |            | text1        |
2  | 2          | 2       | en        | title2     | text2        |
3  | 3          | 2       | en        | title3     |              |
```

My form looks like that :

```
<input name="field1">
<input name="field2_title">
<input name="field2">
<input name="field3_title">
```

My script:

```
var form_data = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url  : '#',
    data : {
        updateData : 1,
        fields : form_data
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so instead

```
<input name="field1">
<input name="field2_title">
<input name="field2">
```

Use this

```
<input name="field[1][content]">
<input name="field[2][title]">
<input name="field[2][content]">
```

So you can use a foreach in php

```
foreach($_POST['field'] AS $id => $elem){
    $content = (isset($elem['content'])) ? $elem['content'] : '';
    $title = (isset($elem['title'])) ? $elem['title'] : '';

    $update = $db->execute("UPDATE content SET title=?, content_text=? WHERE page_id = '".$page_id."' AND lang_code = '".$lang_code."' AND content_id =?", array($title, $content, $id));
}
```

I think this is the easiest way.

Comment: I think this is what I need! I'll mark your answer but there is something wrong with your update query. array($title, $content, $id) must be array($title, $content) and you should add : content_id = '".$id." to the query. Thank you!

Comment: Because HTML is editable by the client and the id is the key of the field it is safer to escape the string at least.

Answer (score 0):

A proper way would be to use an array type input name:

```
<input name="contents[1][title]">
<input name="contents[1][content_text]">
<input name="contents[2][title]">
<input name="contents[2][content_text]">
```

And then you can foreach this array:

```
foreach($_POST['contents'] as $key => $content){
  $sets = array();
  $exec = array();
  if(!empty($content['title'])){
    $sets[] = "title = ?";
    $exec[] = $content['title'];
  }
  if(!empty($content['content_text'])){
    $sets[] = "content_text = ?";
    $exec[] = $content['content_text'];
  }
  if(!empty($sets)){
    $exec[] = $key;
    $set = implode(',', $sets);
    $smt = $db->prepare("UPDATE content SET $set WHERE page_id = ?");
    $smt->execute($exec);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!. What if <input name="contents[1][content_text]"> is not exists in my form? It gives me undefined error if I don't add it to the form. I mean some rows don't need title or some don't need content_text